# Asynch task error when implement GMail API for Android

Tags: android, gmail-api

I am trying to implement **GmailQuickstart** from [GMail API for Android](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) 
I used the same code as in the web page, copied the code to Eclipse. When i run the code on my Samsung device, I can able to select gmail id, allow authentication. Showing Error when retrieve mail.

```
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.createJsonParser(GsonFactory.java:86)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.createJsonParser(GsonFactory.java:76)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.example.gmailquickstart.ApiAsyncTask.getDataFromApi(ApiAsyncTask.java:67)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.example.gmailquickstart.ApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(ApiAsyncTask.java:36)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at com.example.gmailquickstart.ApiAsyncTask.doInBackground(ApiAsyncTask.java:1)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-27 16:06:32.979: E/AndroidRuntime(26644):    ... 5 more
09-27 16:06:50.069: I/Choreographer(26644): Skipped 1019 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644): Activity com.example.gmailquickstart.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419cb7f0 that was originally added here
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.gmailquickstart.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419cb7f0 that was originally added here
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:419)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:322)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:234)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at com.example.gmailquickstart.MainActivity.refreshResults(MainActivity.java:179)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at com.example.gmailquickstart.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:115)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5277)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2671)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-27 16:06:50.919: E/WindowManager(26644):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ApiAsyncTask.java

```
package com.example.gmailquickstart;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * An asynchronous task that handles the Gmail API call.
 * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
 */
public class ApiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param activity MainActivity that spawned this task.
     */
    ApiAsyncTask(MainActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call Gmail API.
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            mActivity.clearResultsText();
            mActivity.updateResultsText(getDataFromApi());

        } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
            mActivity.showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                    availabilityException.getConnectionStatusCode());

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
            mActivity.startActivityForResult(
                    userRecoverableException.getIntent(),
                    MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mActivity.updateStatus("The following error occurred:\n" +
                    e.getMessage());
        }
        if (mActivity.mProgress.isShowing()) {
            mActivity.mProgress.dismiss();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a list of Gmail labels attached to the specified account.
     * @return List of Strings labels.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // Get the labels in the user's account.
        String user = "me";
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListLabelsResponse listResponse =
            mActivity.mService.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        for (Label label : listResponse.getLabels()) {
            labels.add(label.getName());
        }
        return labels;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to include gson.jar in your external lib folder. ( provide by Google ) to parse

Comment: Thanks @dex . I included google-gson-stream-1.7.1 in libs folder. It is working now.

Comment: You are welcome :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to include gson.jar in your external lib folder (provided by Google) to parse the xml.